# Scala: Purpose Like suffix on traits, e.g. IndexSequenceLike

Tags: scala, traits

I see names ending with `Like` for many Scala types. What is the purpose of these traits?
Example would be `IndexSequenceLike`, or `QueryLike`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Like suffix is used for implementation traits, similar to how Java uses "Impl", for the implementation of an interface.

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html

Scala traits are similar to Java interfaces, only better, because traits can contain function definitions, not just declarations.

The `IndexedSeqLike` trait is therefore the implementation of an `IndexedSeq` trait (interface). When added to a class definition, its implementation methods come with it.

This allows code reuse in the Scala library, as well as helping to implement the convention that Iterator should always return the same type.